# trying to find the sum of even fibonacci numbers to 4 million

Tags: java

I am trying to find the sum of the even Fibonacci numbers up untill 4 million.
I found the numbers but i can't get them add up... in the if(n % 2 ==0) loop

```
8
34
144
610
2584
10946
46368
196418
832040
3524578
```

---

```
 public static void number2()
 {
    int number = 40;
    int a, b, c;
    int numLim = 0;
     a = 1;
     b = 2;

    while(numLim < 4000000)
    {
        c = a + b;
        a = b;
        b = c;
        numLim = b;
        if(numLim > 4000000)
        {
             break;
        }
        int sum = 0;
        if(numLim % 2 == 0)
        { 
            System.out.println(numLim);
            sum = sum + numLim;
            System.out.println("sum :" +sum);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do yourself a favor and seperate the fibonacci and the sum into two different methods

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd But the summing is an integral part of sequence generation---you don't suggest OP actually commit all the elements to memory, just to be able to sum them in a separate step?

Comment: You can make this quite a bit faster/simpler by observing that only every third number is even and thus adding every third number.  Calculate three Fibonacci numbers in each loop and use every 3rd.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik ok then have a stateful Fibonacci generator that remembers the last two numbers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must define `sum` outside the `while` loop, or it will become `0` each iteration.

```
int sum = 0;
...
while ...
```

Remember not to set `sum` to 0 each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Euler2 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int fibonacci;
    int num = 0;
    int num2 = 1;
    int loop;
    int sum = 0;
    System.out.println(num2);
        for (loop = 0; loop <= 32; loop++) {
            fibonacci = num + num2;
            num = num2;
            num2 = fibonacci;
            System.out.println("Fibonacci number : " + fibonacci);
        sum += fibonacci;
        System.out.println("This is the sum " +sum);
    }
}
```

}

So I solved it like this, it's a little more efficient and the math works but Euler hates me, hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Euler2 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int fibonacci;
    int num = 0;
    int num2 = 1;
    int loop;
    int sum = 0;
    System.out.println(num2);
        for (loop = 0; loop <= 31; loop++) {
            fibonacci = num + num2;
            num = num2;
            num2 = fibonacci;
            System.out.println("Fibonacci number : " + fibonacci);

            if (fibonacci%2 == 0) {
                sum += fibonacci;
                System.out.println(sum);
            }
        }
}
```

Sorry, this code works.

Comment: This should have been an [edit of your original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/40090220/edit).

Answer (score 0):

Tried doing the above in Java and here is my solution that works

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

        int first = 1;
        int second = 2;
        int sum = 0;
        int sumOfEvenValuedTerms = second;
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            sum = first + second;
            if (sum <= 4000000) {
                if (sum % 2 == 0) {
                    sumOfEvenValuedTerms += sum;
                }

                first = second;
                second = sum;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sumOfEvenValuedTerms);
    }
```

Output is 4613732

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int getSumOfEvenNumbers(int n) {

        int prev = 0;

        int i =1;

        int sum = 0;

        while (i<n){


            int nextNumber = i + prev;

            if(nextNumber %2 ==0) {
                System.out.println(nextNumber);
                sum +=nextNumber;
            }



            prev = i;
            i = nextNumber;
        }

        return sum;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class evenFib {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double a = 1, b = 2, c = 0, sum = 0;
        for (double i = 0; i <= 1000; i++) {
            c = a + b;
            a = b;
            b = c;
            if (c % 2 == 0 && sum < 4000000) {
                sum = sum + c;

            }
        }
        System.out.println(sum + 2);

    }
}
```